# Multiple httpd requests from same IP/session

Tags: apache, http, nginx

I'm hosting a web application (RHEL, ColdFusion11 [tomcat & mod_jk], Apache, load-balancer/traffic manager in front, and 3rd-party CDN) and seeing mini floods of https request from the same IP / session (JSESSION).  The logs show many cases where the same URI is repeated sporadically from 10 to 1000 times per second.  The client IP and agent can differ, and the traffic seems legitimate other than the sporadic occurrence of multiple requests for same URI.

I'm not seeing a pattern with respect to target of http request - can be image, but the pain is felt from calls to non-cached dynamic page.  We see the requests in the logs of our Content Delivery Network, which uses nginx.

The application code has minimal JavaScript.

I'm hoping for ideas for what may be triggering the multiple requests, and ways to mitigate it.  I'd greatly welcome, too, and experiences with mod_evasive.

Thank you!

Comment: Since its a "non-cached dynamic page" I would expect to see a call come in every time a client requests it.   Are you seeing multiple requests from the same client IP & agent?  If you test with only one client how many requests are you seeing?

Comment: Obi1: most requests appear normal - a user (IP + session) will submit post/get for page every 30 secs or so.  (Within same IP, we often have multiple users/sessions)  Every now and then, maybe day or days in between, within the span of maybe 10 minutes, we'll see a user (IP + session) issue 10-1000 requests / sec for the same URI/page.  Haven't seen a pattern for IP or agent.  At this point, we've seen this from a small group of IPs (different domains), and no pattern regarding the agent.  (Usually see expected number of requests when testing or during most hours of operation w/live traffic)

Comment: SOLVED:  This was a result of being attacked with LOIC